# Determine the sum of all multiples of $4$ between $1$ and $999$

Tags: arithmetic, geometric-series

> Determine the sum of all multiples of $4$ between $1$ and $999$.

These types of questions weren't covered in class, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

We're learning about arithmetic and Geometric sequences and series.

I think I should use the formula $S_n=\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d).$

I think $d=4$ and $a=1$?

Comment: You need to compute $4+8+\cdots + 996$. So $a=?$

Comment: How many multiple of 4 smaller than 1000 can you find ? Your sum will go from where to where on which terms ? Can you get the 4 out of that sum ? If yes, do you get a sum that you know ?

Comment: @NAC 4 would be the smallest multiple, which leaves 996 as the largest. Did I provide the correct formula above?

Comment: @Math Lover Thank you! That makes this question make a whole lot more sense!

Comment: What do you think would be $n$ for the formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$4+8+...+996=4(1+2+...+249)$. I think you can continue from here.

Comment: Using the formula, tn=a+(n-1)d to find n=249, then using sn=n/2(a+tn), the answer would be 124,500?

Answer (score 2):

It is
$$4+8+\ldots +996=4(1+2+\ldots+249)$$
Four times an arithmetic series contains $249$ terms with first term $1$ and last term $249$. Hence, the sum is
$$4 \left( \frac{249}{2} (1+249) \right)=124,500$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do is like what Gauss did at his class
$4 + 8 + \cdots + 996 \\ = (4 + 996) + (8 + 992) + \cdots + (496 + 504) + 500 \\ = 1000 \times \dfrac{496}{4} + 500 \\ = 124,500$